# How can I change NSTableView in NSScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview

I'm building a simple data base viewer and for different tables in `database` I need different `TableViews` on my main form (with fixed column's identifier and count). So how can I programmatically change  `NSTableView` in `NSScrollView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
[scrollView setDocumentView:YOUR_TABLEVIEW];